# Phonegap error after retargeting to Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I've created an application using phonegap and it was working fine until I tried to submit it to Microsoft Marketplace. I couldn't do it when target was set to Windows Phone 8.0 ( options in "Store" tab were grayed out).

After retargeting to Windows Phone 8.1 options in "Store" are available but I cannot run this application in simulator because I receive an error:

```
An exception of type 'System.SystemException' occurred in    Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020006.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

I get this error even if I create blank new application. Phonegap version - 3.5.0